# nzload - skiprows not working when 1st column is not matching the table elements

Tags: netezza

When using nzload for fixed width where the first row are headers for the column, the skiprow works fine.  But when I

Works fine if the 1st row has the same number of elements.
1HelloWorld2011-12-07
1HelloWorld2011-12-07
2Netezza   2010-02-16

The first row has a single text that I want nzload to skiprow on but because it's not the same number of elements, nzload throws an error 
DummyRow
1HelloWorld2011-12-07
2Netezza   2010-02-16

Script example:
nzload -t "textFixed_tbl" -format fixed -layout "col1 int bytes 1, col2 char(10) bytes 10, col3 date YMD '-' bytes 10"  -df /tmp/fixed_width.dat -bf /tmp/testFixedWidth.bad -lf /tmp/testFixedWidth.nzlog -skipRows 1 -maxErrors 1

Data File
DummyRow
1HelloWorld2011-12-07
2Netezza   2010-02-16

Error:
Error: Operation canceled
Error: External Table : count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit

Record Format:         FIXED              Record Null-Indicator: 0
  Record Length:         0                  Record Delimiter:

Record Layout: 3 zones :  "col1" INT4 DECIMAL BYTES 1 NullIf &&1 = '',  "col2" CHAR(10) INTERNAL BYTES 10,  "col3" DATE YMD '-' BYTES 10 NullIf &&3 = ''

Statistics

number of records read:      1
  number of bytes read:        22
  number of records skipped:   0
  number of bad records:       1

---

number of records loaded:    0

Elapsed Time (sec): 0.0

Answer (score 0):

The skiprows option for nzload / external tables discards the specified number number of rows, but it still processes the skipped rows. Consequently the rows must be properly formed, and this behavior won't act as you hoped/intended.

This is noted in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/r_load_skiprows.html):

> You cannot use the SkipRows option for header row processing in a data file, because even the skipped rows are processed first. Therefore, data in the header rows should be valid with respect to the external table definition